# Visualise data as graph

Tags: python, graph, data-visualization

I have a dataset of titles from different books. I wish to visualise this using a network graph of the cosine similarity between the title of each book. The books are labelled in two categoires - `1` or `0` - and I would like to colour coordinate based on the category. The cosine similarity between each title should be the weight of the vertice.

To do this I have written this code:

```
cs_title = squareform(pdist(tit.toarray(), 'cosine'))
cs_abstract = squareform(pdist(abst.toarray(), 'cosine'))
X = cs_title + cs_abstract
print(X.shape)
```

which outputs `X` a square matrix of the cosine similarity between each book. I would now like to visualise this using [`graph-tools`](https://graph-tool.skewed.de) in an undirected graph. So far I have written this to instantiate a graph class:

```
g = Graph(directed=False)
```

But am now unsure how to add the data to be visualised.

Comment: The square `X` matrix is called weighted adjacency matrix. If you check for that in the documentation I'm pretty sure that graph-tool should have a way to load an adjacency matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following code you can convert an adjacency matrix into a graph:

```
g = graph_tool.Graph(directed = False)
        g.add_vertex(len(X))
        edge_weights = g.new_edge_property('double')
        for i in range(X.shape[0]):
            for j in range(X.shape[1]):
                if i > j and X[i,j] != 0:
                    e = g.add_edge(i, j)
                    edge_weights[e] = X[i,j]
        graph_draw(g, vertex_text=g.vertex_index, vertex_font_size=18, output_size=(200, 200), output="two-nodes.png")
```

Note: This does not colour co-ordinate as requested.